# Cannot start VNC Server: Error opening security policy file

Tags: 18.04, vnc

I installed VNC server via

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

When I try to run vncserver command, the service does not start.

The content of the log file under .vnc is as follows:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Wed Dec 25 06:41:00 2019
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 2371
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 148 requests (148 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What was the command you used (omit any user/passwords, if any)?

Did you kill the process or did it crash?

Comment: Actually I was trying to solve my another issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194213/bugged-screen-while-using-vnc). I tried different VNC server programs (vnc4server, tightvncserver, tigervnc) and eventually broke the system :).

Comment: @JayM I don't know it crashed but the last time I killed it via `vncserver -kill :1` command.

Comment: I partly fixed my issue by deleting `/etc/vnc.conf` file and then restarting vncserver again.

Comment: Yes the /etc/vnc.conf file is the issue, which is left in the systems when tigervnc is installed. It doesn't clean up the file even if we purge all tigervnc pacakges.

Comment: @PushpakDagade, could you post your comment as answer?